# Hashmap not replacing the correct items

Tags: java, reference, hashmap, compare

I'm trying to replace Hotel_A with the new value when running the methods in main. But the wrong values are being inserted for the keys.

For example, when you change Hotel_A to take test1, Hotel_B takes the value. I've debugged through it, and the logic of the if statements is correct. I think the fetchImage method is incorrect and is finding the wrong Hotel.

Output expected:

Size: 2

Hotel_A: [B@3dfeca64

Hotel_B: [B@1aa8c488

Output received:

Size: 2

Hotel_A: [B@1aa8c488

Hotel_B: [B@3dfeca64

```
public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ImageStore i = new ImageStore();
        byte[] test1 = { (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x1f };
        byte[] test2 = { (byte) 0x0a, (byte) 0x1d };

        //Functionality test part 1
        System.out.println("Functionality test part 1");
        i.storeImage("Hotel_A",test2);
        i.storeImage("Hotel a",test2);
        i.storeImage("Hotel B",test1);

        //"The store should have size 2"
        System.out.println("Size: " + i.size());

        //"And contain imageA (test1) and imageB (test2)"
        System.out.println("Hotel_A: " + i.fetchImage("Hotel_A"));
        System.out.println("Hotel_B: " + i.fetchImage("Hotel_B"));

        i.imageObj.clear();


        //Functionality test part 2
        System.out.println("\nFunctionality test part 2");
        i.storeImage("Hotel_A", test1);
        i.storeImage("Hotel a", test1);
        i.storeImage("Hotel_A", test2); //Example included syntax error, important?
        i.storeImage("Hotel a",test2);

        //"The store should have size 1"
        System.out.println("Size:" + i.size());

        //"and only contain imageB"
        System.out.println("Hotel_A: " + i.fetchImage("Hotel_A"));

    }
}



import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ImageStore {

    //Declaration of HasMap for id/ byte array storage
    Map<String, byte[]> imageObj = new HashMap<String, byte[]>();

  /**
   * Inserts an image in the store
   *
   * @param id -- The identifier of the image
   * @param content -- The content of the image
   */
  public void storeImage (String id, byte[] image) {
      //Check's input 
      //If Equal to 'Hotel_A' or similar, saves to 'Hotel_A' index
      if (id.equals("Hotel_A") || id.equals("Hotel_a") || 
              id.equals("Hotel A") || id.equals("Hotel a"))
      {
          imageObj.put("Hotel_A",image);
      }

      //Else if equal to 'Hotel_B' or similar, saves to 'Hotel_B' index
      else if (id.equals("Hotel_B") || id.equals("Hotel_b")
              || id.equals("Hotel B") || id.equals("Hotel b"))
      {
          imageObj.put("Hotel_B",image);
      }
  }


  /**
   * Retrieves an image from the store
   *
   * @param id -- The identifier of the image to be retrieved
   * @return the image content
   */   
  public byte[] fetchImage(String id) {
      return imageObj.get(id);
  }

  /**
   * The size of the store
   *
   * @return the actual store size
   */
  public int size() {
    return imageObj.size();
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what do you expect to happen when running this code, and what happens instead?

Comment: I expect the values put into Hotel_A to print first, then the values of Hotel_B to print second. It appears to work, but if you change Hotel_A to accept test2, the new value will appear second rather than first, which means either it's printing Hotel_B when it should be printing Hotel_A, or they're being assigned wrongly

Comment: Please be precise. Edit your question and paste the output you get from the program. Then print the output you expect to get, and explain why.

Comment: Okay, I've done that

Comment: I strongly recommend changing to the test program to produce more meaningful output. Currently you are getting the hash code of an array, which is run and system dependent. For example, `Arrays.toString( i.fetchImage("Hotel_A"))`

Comment: Very bad idea to things this way. Maps are designed to rely on equals/hashCode. You should create your own class that represents "hotels"; and override equals/hashCode in there to do the right thing. Instead, you moved the knowledge of what makes two hotels equal into your map implementation. This means: whenever other parts of your code are dealing with "hotels" ... you will probably duplicate your comparing code. As said: don't go there.

Comment: How do you know if `[B@1aa8c488` is `test1` or `test2`? What you see there is the type of the array (`[B`, which means byte array), followed by the hashCode of the array (`1aa8c488`), which has nothing to do with what the array contains. Print your arrays using `Arrays.toString(array)`.

Comment: @Jägermeister The class being used for the key, String, has perhaps the best tested equals and hashCode in the whole Java world.

Comment: Mmm, I feel i've been a bit of an idiot then. Using the toString showed I was getting the correct values after all. My bad Thanks!

Comment: @Patricia Shanahan Do you wanna post it as an answer for rep?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Sure. But: he defines "equal" for his strings as: "Hotel A" should be equal to "Hotel a" and "Hotel_A". If these are the desired semantics, then he should not be using string objects as key. Creating a specialized map that uses string keys, but treats them in a very non-string way ... is simply wrong. It creates code that stops "being maintain-able" the second you close the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a toString() to the fetchImage shows I had the correct values after all. My bad. Thank you Particia Shanahan